# Working out the length of the 3rd side of an isosceles triangle- Pythagoras' theorem

Tags: trigonometry

I have been revising some maths equations and see that you can work out the third side of an isosceles triangle using the formula $\sqrt2 x$

$x$ being one of the equal sides.

Could someone explain how this works?

I understand the theorem:

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

But, I am struggling to understand the relationship between the two formulas.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you speaking of an isosceles *right* triangle?

Comment: This will only be true in the special case where the isosceles triangle is also a right-angled triangle.

Comment: In the case of a general isosceles triangle, the angle bisector between the two equal sides is also an altitude/perpendicular to the third side.  Thus this would divide the isosceles triangle into two right triangles, and if the length of the altitude is known, the third side's length can be found by an application of the Pythagorean formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

and $a=b$:

$$a^2 + a^2 = 2 a^2 = c^2$$

You can indeed find the third side of the right triangle with the following formula:

$$\sqrt{2 a^2} = \sqrt{c^2}$$
$$\sqrt{2} a = c$$

Both sides having the same length allows you to turn the sum into a product, which you can partially calculate the square root of. (or at least calculate the root and be able to write down the result in a finite amount of time)

If the angle between the 2 sides of equal length is not 90°, you can start from the general formula for the third side, which also includes the angle $\alpha$ between them:

$$a^2 + b^2 -2ab\cos (\alpha)= c^2$$

again $a=b$:

$$a^2 + a^2 -2aa\cos (\alpha)=2a^2(1-\cos (\alpha))= c^2$$

unfortunately, the angle is still there and the formula does not simplify as much as it does for the special case of 90°.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$

$$a = b = 1$$

$$(1)^2 + (1)^2 = 2$$

$$ c = \sqrt2$$

I simply plugged in $1$ for $ a $ and $ b $ so that the relationship would show best. $c = \sqrt2*(1)$